# Getting the SCNRenderer from an instantiated SCNScene

Tags: swift, scenekit

I would like to know how I am supposed to extract the SCNRenderer from an instantiated SceneKit scene. I am trying to get the AVAudioEngine which lies in the SCNRenderer so that I can apply audio filters to my nodes.

Here is the override `didFinishLaunching` part reduced to relevant code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()
    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)
    // set the scene to the view
    self.gameView!.scene = scene
    gameView.delegate = self
}
```

Please if someone can give me a pointer, I would really appreciate it as I was able to run sounds in positional but now am stuck with using the AVEngine graph to do stuff like:

AVAudioInput > AVAudioUnitDistortion > AVAudioOutput and start doing some fun mixing.

Edit:

This is what I had in mind for the engine:

```
    distortion = AVAudioUnitDistortion()

    let URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath+"/welcome.aiff")
            if(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(dataPath+"/welcome.aiff")){
                            let source = SCNAudioSource(URL: URL)!
                source.volume = 30.0
                source.reverbBlend = 50.0
                source.rate = 0.9
                let clip = SCNAudioPlayer(source: source)
                engine = clip.audioNode!.engine
                distortion.loadFactoryPreset(AVAudioUnitDistortionPreset.SpeechRadioTower)
                engine.attachNode(distortion)
                engine.connect(clip.audioNode!, to: distortion, format: nil)
                engine.connect(self.distortion, to: engine.outputNode, format: nil)
                return clip
```

But I am now having a null pointer exception over the distortion AVAudioUnitDistortion instance.

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`audioEngine` is a property on the `SCNSceneRenderer` protocol, not on the `SCNRenderer` class. <del>Since `SCNScene` conforms to `SCNSceneRenderer`, `scene.audioEngine` will work.</del>

edit:
Since `SCNView` conforms to `SCNSceneRenderer`, `gameView.audioEngine` will work.

Comment: Ok, but scene which I have instantiated does not have audioEngine.

Comment: That's `SCNView` and `view.audioEngine`, not `scene`.